# Deleting Hardlink To System File On Win10

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, hardlink

I have hard links into system files *advapi32.dll*, *kernel32.dll* and etc.

I have used [MoveFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx) API for deletion with *MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT*, it basically uses *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager::PendingFileRenameOperations* registry to delete during reboot. I have also included [AllowProtectedRenames](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/506546-pendingfilerenameoperations-failed/) hack.

Without *AllowProtectedRenames* there have been many failures, but with this set, there are still a few files (hard links) that cannot be removed in Windows 10.

I wonder if there is any way to get rid of such links without loading external OS, as this issue is in multiple machines.

Comment: Why would you actually remove those? Where are those links? Especially both files you mentioned are pretty important for the system to actually run?

Comment: @Seth there is poorly made tool which have generated bunch of garbage in multiple machines. So I want to do cleanup.

Comment: If it's additional stuff you should be able to easily remove it by reversing the steps from that tool. As an example if you do have the hard link in a directory with an application stop that application first. The application directory is usually one of the first directories that dependencies such as DLLs are searched for. What is the actual error message you're seeing? Using a backup would probably be the easiest option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked entire list of files that are in problem, so noticed that the problem with deletion is only with *KnownDlls*. So I have added all files into [ExcludeFromKnowDlls](http://systemmanager.ru/win2k_regestry.en/69679.htm) list. This way OS doesn't lock them and on reboot deletion succeeds. This, however, requires additional reboot to restore original (empty) value of [ExcludeFromKnowDlls](http://systemmanager.ru/win2k_regestry.en/69679.htm).